# Incremento en bucle For no funciona

Tags: c#, loops

Tengo una bucle `for` que no me funciona correctamente. Si hago un Debug, el incremento siempre se resetea a 0 por ende solo llega a 1.

Aquí está parte del código:

Primeramente hago una bucle `for` para llamar el userID

```
var userDataId = client.GetUser(DataSourceId); 

for (int i = 0; i < userDataId.Length; i++)
{ 
    string[] multiUserIDs = new string[] { userDataId[i].List[0].ToString() };

    WS.TaskEntry[] resultGT3 = client.GetTasks3(multiUserIDs);

    for (int s = 0; s < resultGT3.Length; s++)
    {
      file.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}",
      resultGT3[s].ProjectID,
      resultGT3[s].UserID,
      resultGT3[s].ProjectTitle,
      resultGT3[s].StartDate);
    }

}
```

Aquí el `s++` siempre se pone en 0 y solo va hacia 1.

También lo he intentado con `while`, pero tiene el mismo resultado:

```
int s = 0;
while (s < resultGT3.Length)
{                                            
  file.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}",
  resultGT3[s].ProjectID,
  resultGT3[s].UserID,
  resultGT3[s].ProjectTitle,
  resultGT3[s].StartDate);
  ++s;
}
```

¿Me podrían ayudar a identificar que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que `resultGT3.Length != 0 o 1`?

Comment: de que tipo es  `resultGT3`?

Comment: Hola, si estoy seguro. En el resto de mi cogido, uno de los parametros que viene de resultGT3 obtiene varios resultados en su clase

Comment: Verificaste mediante debug cuanto vale `resultGT3.Length` ?

Comment: Por favor añade el código donde se declara y asigna `resultGT3`

Comment: Listo, ya agregue el resto del codigo, gracias

Comment: Según lo que has agregado lo más probable es que `GetTasks3` siempre devuelva solo 1 elemento, por lo que `s` nunca pasa de 1

Comment: @Aarancibia una duda, cuando defines la linea string[] multiUserIDs = new string[] { userDataId[i].List[0].ToString() };  solo indicas un unico id para recuperar con el GetTasks3() no sera por eso que siempre devuelve un unico item ?  vuelvo a plantear que definas un breakpoint y evalues la variable

Comment: si eso hago, pongo un break point ahi mismo y cada vez que pasa por el primer for, el userID cambia

Comment: @Aarancibia entonces cual seria el problema ? si la entidad cambia quiere decir que "s" esta cambiando tambien. Igual con el breakpoint apuntaba a que menciones si obtienes mas de un item en "resultGT3" porque la forma en que invocas a GetTasks3() solo le pasas un unico userid como filtro

Comment: Tiene sentido, porque el resultado final escribe el mismo userID muchas veces. De que forma entonces prodia obtener todos los usersID provenientes de UserDataId?

Comment: @Aarancibia lo que me genera dudas es esto userDataId[i].List[0].ToString()  como puede un array tener a su ves una lista? y porque tomas solo el item cero de esta

Comment: Hola, solo tomo el cero de la lista porque en la position cero se encuentra el UserID que necesito en el GetTask3. los otros parametros no son mandatorios para poder llamar al metodo

Answer (score 1):

> el incremento siempre se resetea a 0 por ende solo llega a 1.

Seguramente el valor de resultGT3.Length es 1 y esa sea la razón por la cual no ves cambio:

```
for (int s = 0; s < resultGT3.Length; s++)
{
  file.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}",
  resultGT3[s].ProjectID,
  resultGT3[s].UserID,
  resultGT3[s].ProjectTitle,
  resultGT3[s].StartDate);
}
```

Comment: Hola si es verdad, segun el debug el userID contiene string[1] siempre. Tengo mas arriba otro for que contiene (int i = 0; i < userDataId.Length; i++) y es ese UserID que pongo en el resultGT3. Editare la pregunta para agregar esa parte del codigo

Comment: ya agregue el resto del codigo, gracias

Answer (score 0):

**>>De que forma entonces prodia obtener todos los usersID provenientes de UserDataId?**

Teniendo en cuenta que el servicio `GetTasks3()` puede recibir una lista de IDs, podrias enviar un array con varios  si previamente los acumulas en una lista antes de invocar al metodo.

```
var userDataId = client.GetUser(DataSourceId); 

List<string> multiUserIDs = new List<string>();

foreach (var userdata in userDataId)
{ 
    multiUserIDs.Add(userdata.List[0].ToString());
}

WS.TaskEntry[] resultGT3 = client.GetTasks3(multiUserIDs.ToArray());

foreach (var result in resultGT3)
{
  file.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}",
      result.ProjectID,
      result.UserID,
      result.ProjectTitle,
      result.StartDate);
}
```

Observaras que ahora los for no estan anidados

Comment: implemente tu recomendacion, y en el multiUserIDs.ToArray() de resultGT3 haciendo un breakpoint veo bien que todos los IDs estan ahi (son 11 en todal) al llegar al forach. El se ejecuta varias veces solo dandome el primer UserID repetidamente sin agregar todos los demas que obtuvo anteriormente

Comment: bien esto que comentas es un avance, a cual foreach te refieres cuando dices que llegas ?  dices que da el mismo userid, pero no sera que la lista que devuelve GetTasks3() es la misma entidad ? si inspeccionas con el mouse esa lista puede ver que los userid son distintos?

Comment: bueno si el multiUserIDs.ToArray() contiene la lista completa de differentes UserIS, pero cuando paso el mouse por el resultGT3 solo me da un resultado [0] el cual contiene siempre el mismo userID. No importa cuantas veces lo ejecute haciendo el F5 en el miso lugar, siempre obtiene el mimso USerID resultGT3. Esto es una aplicacion de consola, pero si pruebo el mismo concepto en un Windows Form (textBox1.Text += resultGT3[s].UserID) los UsersID van cambiando. Que puedo hacer con el resultGT3?

Comment: pero entonces resultGT3() devuelve un unico resultado no una lista a pesar que envies un array de IDs. Podrias consultar con la persona que creo el servicio para validar como responde internamente cuando envias varios IDs quizas el servicio tiene un bug que debe solucionarse para que retorne una lista

Comment: Segun la persona quien desarrollo el servicio, este deberia poder devolver varios userIds si provienen de una lista. De la unica forma que he sido capaz de hacerlo es cuando he tenido el Windows form usando += pero no bucleando con la consola y asi poder escribir en el archivo de salida que quiero crear

Comment: no entendi, que haces con el += ? o sea es un array de IDs lo que debes enviar o es un string con los IDs separados ? creo que deberias consultar con esta persona si con el codigo que implementas deberia funcionar, para que este la evalue y te de recomendaciones. El codigo entiendo esta bien implementado, pero hay algo que el servicio no esta devolviendo lo que esperas

Comment: Tienes toda la razon, voy a consultarlo con el y ya cuando tenga toda la informacion voy a poner el comentario aqui. muchas gracias por toda la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Encontré el problema y ya pude solucionarlo.

En la primera línea de mi código:

```
var userDataId = client.GetUser(DataSourceId);
```

En vez de poner el resultado en la variable `var userDataId` lo cambie por:

```
UserData[] userDataId = client.GetUserData(DataSourceId);
```

De esta forma pude poner todos los UsersIDs y ya pude obtener lo que estaba buscando.